# Frequently use of 'UPDATE STATISTICS WITH FULLSCAN' is normal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Some months ago, my Asp.net application gave me a timeout exception while executing a simple select on the database, with specific where values.

Strangely, without the where clause (or different values), the select returns the result without timeout.

This error was solved by executing 'UPDATE STATISTICS WITH FULLSCAN' in all tables.

After 3 months, the timeout error occurs again, and again it was solved with update statistics.

This error start to occur frequently, and then I developed a service with a timer to execute the update automatically.

The need of use Update Statistics become monthly, and after weekly, and after daily, in each hour and now in each 15 minutes!

This is not normal, right? And what are the best practices to avoid this issue?

The database is not small. The actual size is almost 1 gigabyte (this problem starts when database was around 300 MB).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to update statistics every 15 minutes. My guess is that there's a parameter sniffing issue. A statistics update is just forcing a recompile and masks the issue until a bad parameter is cached.

Do some homework on parameter sniffing. Look at the query plan before & after statistics update. Sometimes you can solve these types of issues by adding a recompile hint to the query or better indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have maintenance plans running on the database?

If not, check out http://ola.hallengren.com/ for some cool free code for backup, defrag indexes and update statistics.

Do you have update statistics set on for the database?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx

It is a fact of life that data is entered in the database and statistics get out of shape.  There is a magic number that tells the database when to automatically update the stats.  It is based on row count entered.  Search the SQL Server Internals book for the answer.

To ensure you have the latest stats, just run a job to maintain them.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a very common problem.  As rsd808 mentions this is probably because the SQL Server has incorrectly cached the wrong plan for a particular query.  CRAFTY DBA's recommendation of Ola Hallengren's maintenance scripts is also sage advice.

It would help considerably if you included some details of the query that was causing the problem.  In cases where I have seen this problem it has often been related to very innocuous User Defined Functions being used.

If UDFs are indeed the problem, one of the causes can be that you are using the same UDF in two different scenarios.  When the query is first analysed by the query optimizer it may find that only a few rows match.  This will optimise the query to then use a particular plan from that point on - *regardless of whether other cases may need to scan thousands of rows*.

As mentioned - update statistics on a 15 minute basis is very much overkill and *can* hurt performance by asking SQL server to re-evaluate *every* query every 15 minutes, rather than being able to store optimised plans for longer.

Use the excellent resources available at **www.brentozar.com** to help analyse which queries are the heaviest hitting.  Brent has a YouTube channel with - I believe - the most valuable free resources online for performance troubleshooting servers and improving performance of queries.  His cast on fixing slow queries even uses the StackOverflow database!